# Can't save variables from OnGet()

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm having some trouble saving variables and objects when using the `OnGet()` method. When doing like shown below, `TestNumber` isn't getting set. Same if I try to create an object and set it in the `OnGet()` method.

Any clue on why this is happening?

```
public class TestPageModel : PageModel
    {
        public int TestInt { get; set; }

        public TestPageModel() {
            TestInt = 0;
        }

        public void OnGet() {
            TestInt = 5;
        }

        public void OnPost() {
            Console.WriteLine(TestInt);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To get the value assigned in OnGet method, you need to pass the value
>   to the view first, and then pass it to the OnPost method as a
>   parameter.

```
public class TestPageModel : PageModel
{ 
    public int TestInt { get; set; }

    public TestPageModel()
    {
        TestInt = 0;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        TestInt = 5;
    }

    public void OnPost(int TestInt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TestInt);
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
      <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="@Model.TestInt"  name="TestInt"/>
      <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, okay thanks! What if I need to create an object in the OnGet method that I want to be stored in the same class?